# RxJS5 - wait for 2 http calls, then listen to socket

Tags: rxjs5

I have a scenario where

1. I need to call 2 http services wait for them both
2. Call some method
3. Start listening to a socket which will next often
4. Each time socket streams, call some other method

If it matters, I am using Angular2.

What I have now is separate (and working).

I am wondering how I can create this in all one series of operators to guarantee the waiting for first 2 calls without having to use local vars? - if that even makes sense to do...

What I am working with:

```
this.sub1 = Observable
    .forkJoin([http.get(/api1), http.get('/api2')])
        .subscribe(([api1ResData, api2ResData]) => {
            this.doSomething(api1ResData, api2ResData);
        });

this.sub2 = socket.get('api3')
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.doSomethingElse(api3ResData);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `this.doSomething(api1ResData, api2ResData)` is an async function returning Observable or Promise, and you want to use the result of that operation in the next one, you can use `switchMap` or `mergeMap` to output the result into another observable, then subscribe to it to do the socket operation, like:

```
this.sub1 = Observable
.forkJoin([http.get(/api1), http.get('/api2')])
.switchMap(([api1ResData, api2ResData]) => {
    return this.doSomething(api1ResData, api2ResData)
})
.switchMap(doSomethingResult => {
    return socket.get('api3')
})
.subscribe(socketGetResult => {
    this.doSomethingElse(api3ResData);
});
```

If `this.doSomething(api1ResData, api2ResData)` returns another type synchronously or is void, then you can just to a `.do` operator (In case you don't need `doSomething` result), or a `.map` otherwise, if you use `doSomething` result in `socket.get(3)`

```
this.sub1 = Observable
.forkJoin([http.get(/api1), http.get('/api2')])
.do(([api1ResData, api2ResData]) => {
   this.doSomething(api1ResData, api2ResData)
})
.switchMap(([api1res, api2res]) => {
    return socket.get('api3')
})
.subscribe(socketGetResult => {
    this.doSomethingElse(api3ResData);
});
```

You still use `switchMap` for the `socket.get()` operation, as you need to map to another observable, and receives the previous `forkJoin` result as the `.do` operator is to execute code without changing the current observable.

Check [switchMap official docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap)

Comment: Thank-you for the information. Trying out the async version I get a type error:     Argument of type '([api1ResData, api2ResData]: any[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any[], index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.

Comment: Hi, can you check if you have set both the `return` statements, and if so, could you tell me which of the 2 switchMaps gives you the error? Also, check that both socket.get and this.doSomething are returning either a promise or an observable. Here, try to specify to the source of those functions that they return any of those types.

Comment: Thank-you for your time. The issue is that this.doSomething does not return observable, it is just a normal method with nothing returned. (Same case for doSomethingElse)

Comment: Use de .do() version in this case, as it's like a syncrhonous undefined return ;) Same with the socket.get() actually, maybe you can even do both on the same `.do()` block if you don't need the result in the following subscribe

Comment: My fault, I misunderstood what you said the first time around. This works great and rx is starting to sink in. Thank-you for your patience!